# What's the Ruby analogue of npm link?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

If you the source for a Nodejs project, the command `npm link` installs it in such a way that any changes you make apply everywhere without you having to reinstall.

> npm link is designed to install a development package and see the changes in real time without having to keep re-installing it.

https://www.npmjs.org/doc/misc/npm-developers.html#link-packages

Is there a analogue for Ruby projects?

Answer (score 1):

The Ruby equivalent is to use the `:path` option when specifying a gem in your Gemfile.  It would look something like this.

```
gem "mylocalgem", :path => "/path/to/local/gem/dir/"
```

If you are trying to do this globally on the default system ruby then you can do one of the following.

```
gem install --local path_to_gem/filename.gem
```

or just run the following from the directory where the .gem file exists and it will be picked up.

```
gem install
```

Comment: Sorry I probably didn't explain it very well: `npm link` installs the package globally, but symlinks your source folder, so it'll be picked up everywhere

Comment: I've added some additional information; that I believe is what you are trying to do based on your feedback.

Comment: But you still need to build the .gem file everytime you change the code. Is there a way to installing the source code globally in a symlinked way instead of the gem file?  
I guess I can create an alias for the actual executable as in `ruby /path/to/gem/bin`, but I think it'd be helpful if it was done the other way.